# sharedarraybuffer error in edge and firefox but not in chrome when uploading with ffmpeg in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ffmpeg, cross-origin-opener-policy

I have the code below in React.js that uses ffmpeg to convert files:

```
import { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';

  const doTranscode = async () => {
    setMessage('Loading ffmpeg-core.js');
    await ffmpeg.load();
    setMessage('Uploading file');
    ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', filename, await fetchFile(file));
    await ffmpeg.run('-i', filename, 'test.wav');
    setMessage('Upload to manager complete. Sound file will be available and playable on the manger within 1-2 minutes.');
    const data = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'test.wav');
    setAudioSrc(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'audio/wav' })));

    var file_name = prompt('What would you like to call this file?');

    if (!file_name) {
      file_name = Date.now()
    }
    
    (async function(){
      let output = await getSoundID(customer_id, file_name);
      let sound_id = output.data;
      var bucket_file = new File([new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'audio/wav' })], "sounds/" + customer_id + "/" + sound_id + ".wav");
      uploadFileToS3(bucket_file);
      updateSoundData(sound_id, customer_id);
    })();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (file) {
      doTranscode()
    }
  }, [file])
```

The code above works great in Chrome and the files are successfully converted. However, when I bring it to Firefox or Edge I get this error `Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): SharedArrayBuffer is not defined`.

I looked up this issue and they said I need to modify my headers to include this:

```
You need to set two response headers for your document:

Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

Not sure how I would this in my JS code?

Would love to hear what you guys think.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like according to [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg) the `@ffmpeg/ffmpeg` library only supports the browsers which have SharedArrayBuffer:

> Only browsers with SharedArrayBuffer support can use ffmpeg.wasm, you can check [HERE](https://caniuse.com/sharedarraybuffer) for the complete list.

The list above contains Edge starting from version 79 and Firefox starting from version 79.

Comment: I'm on Firefox 90.0.2

Comment: Does in work at [the library demo page](https://ffmpegwasm.github.io/#demo) in your browser?