# How to detect if a browser supports SharedArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, browser-feature-detection, sharedarraybuffer

I'm using ffmpeg.wasm in my site but it [only works if the browser supports SharedArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68567821/2414842). Is there a simple way to test using javascript (browser js or nodejs) if the browser has support to it? One solution I thought was to compare the user agent with the list offered in [this website](https://caniuse.com/sharedarraybuffer) but this would be too verbose and I'm guessing if there isn't a simpler way?

Comment: `if( typeof SharedArrayBuffer !== 'undefined' ) { `

Comment: Dare I ask what kind of performance you get from FFmpeg in WASM? Somehow I doubt you'll be able to do much in the way of H.265 encoding with a single JS thread.

Comment: I'm using to convert mp4 videos to hls format to offload this work from my server to the client, but indeed is kinda slow

Comment: MP4 and HLS are orthogonal. You can serve MP4 using HLS. You do not need to transcode files either.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that but the easiest way of finding out is just checking [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=sharedarraybuffer),
but if you want to do it runtime you can add this line of code in your browser

```
try{
   var sab = new SharedArrayBuffer(1024);
   if(sab===undefined)throw new Error('not supported')
}
catch(e){
alert('browser doesnot support SharedArrayBuffer: ",e)
}
```